# in datatable initComplete not called after table.ajax.reload();

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, datatable

In a datatable on `initComplete` I wrote some code. The first time it works fine but after calling `table.ajax.reload()` the `initComplete` is not performing in the datatable.

```js
"initComplete": function(settings, json) {
  $("#customerBids tr.cls-x-setTr").each(function() {
    debugger;
    var trId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + trId + ' td').hide();
    $('#' + trId).append('<td class="cls-x-tmpTD" colspan="18"> </td>');
  });
},
```

I added this interval which created the issue:

```
timer = setInterval(function() { 
  table.ajax.reload(null, false); 
}, 15000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first argument of `reload()` is the reference of a callback function to execute. As such you can extract your `initComplete()` logic to its own function which is called from both events. Try this:

```
// in datatable settings:
"initComplete": foo,

// your reload logic:
timer = setInterval(function() { 
  table.ajax.reload(foo, false); // note 'foo' here
}, 15000);

// somewhere outside of your datatable definition:
function foo() {
  $("#customerBids tr.cls-x-setTr").each(function() {
    debugger;
    var trId = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#' + trId + ' td').hide();
    $('#' + trId).append('<td class="cls-x-tmpTD" colspan="18"> </td>');
  });
}
```